# Access-Control-Allow-Origin socket io

Tags: node.js, sockets, same-origin-policy

i have problem with connection of socket io in node js 
i get this error when client wants to connect

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ip:2222/socket.io/?username=MetR2I7&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdUrPH5. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

and i search for this probelem but not work anything in my project
my server cod is below

```
var app = require('express')();
 var server = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});
 var redis = require('redis');
 var request = require('request');
 var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");


server.listen(2222);
// io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'htmlfile', 'flashsocket']);
//    io.set('origins', '*:*');
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
}
```

and my client js:

```
  var io = require('socket.io-client');
  var c = io.connect('http://ip:2222', {query: "username=" + "MetR2I7"});
```

Comment: `COR` issue comes with browser. It should not come with `node` socket.io client. Also, I tried browser specific client as well, still no error.

Comment: how can i fix it ?@MukeshSharma